# What's the difference between function variables and normal functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I was wondering. If I create functions in JavaScript, they're like this:

```
function myFunc(param){
 //Something to do
}
```

However, I also see tutorials where they create functions like:

```
var myFunc = fucntion(param){
 //Something to do
}
```

Is there a difference between the two and what are the pros and cons?